# Firebase database security rules to allow anonymous as well as web access

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Below rules on my firebase database allow anonymous logins through my iOS app.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "locations": {
      ".indexOn": "g"
    }
    }
}
```

That works well but now I need to add access for my JS web app which works through the apiKey. How do I add that rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you login anonymously on the JS web app? I copied this code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

if you don't want to login (which I don't think you want to), just replace

```
auth != null
```

with

```
true
```

Comment: If we replace auth != null with true, then what would be the point of anonymous login ? Plus the APIs will be exposed. e.g., In my app I want Anonymous login as some APIs are fetched before a user logs in. To do that, I'm using tokenId generated from anonymous login and passing that to end of my API call. However, when I'm trying to run the code, It says 401 unauthorised. Any idea how we can achieve this ?